# Use country flags insted of text as labels of a facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found solutions to add flags instead of the name of the country as label for a categorical variables as axis.

However, these do not work when I want to label with a flag the rows of plots (y-axis) within a

`facet_grid(Country ~ Year, switch = "y")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have some urls to the flags you want, you can use `element_markdown` from `ggtext`. If you only have country names in the column, then this little function will help:

```r
get_flag <- function(data, column) {
  data[[column]] <- paste0("<img 
  src='https://www.sciencekids.co.nz/images/pictures/flags96/",
                           data[[column]], ".jpg' width='100' /><br>*",
                           data[[column]], '*')
  data
}
```

So now you can do

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(get_flag(df, 'Country'), aes(Set, Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(Country ~ Year, switch = 'y') +
  theme(strip.text.y.left = element_markdown(angle = 0),
        strip.placement = 'outside')
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2020:2023, each = 6),
                 Value = rnorm(24),
                 Set = rep(rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 3), length = 24),
                 Country = rep(c('Canada', 'Scotland', 'Mexico'), length = 24))
```

Comment: I still want to use the original values for the fact, since they are a factor.
I just want to change the label.

Comment: @GiulioGCantone that's easy to fix though - see my update.

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thx.

Answer (score 5):

The **ragg** package enables the AGG graphics backend, which fully supports advanced text features, including emoji. This makes it easy to include any national flag anywhere you could use a text string (axes, facet labels, plot labels, etc.), and you can leverage the emoji set built into your OS rather than hunting for your own graphic resources.

RStudio can be configured to use the AGG renderer as its backend (Settings -> General -> Graphics), and `ggsave()` can also use this backend to save plots:

```
library(ragg)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  country = c(' Canada', ' United States', ' Mexico')
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = 1)) +
  facet_grid(facets = ~country)

ggsave('flags.png', width = 4, height = 2, device = agg_png)
```

[image]